# Status changes by calling openstack api from Beego, Reactjs

Tags: api, go, controller, openstack, beego

**We're using:**

Backend - Beego (golang)

Frontend - Reactjs

Server - Openstack

**So:**

When reactjs calls listSomethingAPI, I calls openstackAPI and Openstack gives me that List.

it has some fields like this:

`id | name | status`

**Problem is:**

When Frontend calls PUT api, I calls API. But Openstack status change takes almost 10 seconds

**Question:**

How do i know status changes when frontend calls PUT api

**Solution that i found:**

frontend calls ListAPI every 5 seconds.

**We cant use**:

Websocket, AJAX

Is there any way to solve this problem?